# How to remove large number of files/folders in linux

Tags: linux, nfs, hadoop

We are using hadoop to split a table into smaller files to feed to mahout, but in the process, we created a huge amount of _temporary logs.

We have an NFS mount for the hadoop volume so we can use all the linux commands to delete folders files, but we just can't get them to be deleted, here's what I've tried so far:

```
hadoop fs -rmr /.../_temporary  : hangs for hours and does nothing
```

on NFS mount:

```
rmr -rf /.../_temporary :hangs for hours and does nothing

find . -name '*.*' -type f -delete : same as above
```

The folders look like this (38 of these folders inside _temporary):

```
drwxr-xr-x 319324 user user 319322 Oct 24 12:12 _attempt_201310221525_0404_r_000000_0
```

The content of these are actually folders, not files. Each one of those 319322 folders has exactly one file inside. Not sure why the do the logging this way.

Comment: `-type f` is going to find regular files. You want `-type d` if you are using `find` to locate folders

Comment: Just a little comment on @Matt's suggestions: `-name '*.*'` is not needed if you used just `-type d`, maybe I would use something like this: `find . -type d -delete` or `find . -name "_temporary" -delete` (depending on the exact case, maybe there are files which shouldn't be deleted).

Comment: tried it, it hangs forever and doesn't delete the files :/

Comment: Were you ever able to resolve this? Running into the exact same issue in OS X.

Answer (score 1):

Does an `rm`, `rm -r`, or `rmdir` work on the individual file or directory respectively?

If so, I'll bet you're waiting on NFS to sort the 319222 folder names and present them alphabetically. Try `ls -f | xargs rm -r`